# How to close "Location access" screen after enabling GPS?

Tags: gps

There's an application I use that prompts the user to enable GPS, but then I'm stuck in this screen not knowing how to close it:

[image]

As there's no check/OK button, how do I actually enable GPS and get on with it?

Thank you.

Comment: Just click Back (the sideways triangle at the bottom), it should take you back to your app and just work. Note that if you are on Marshmallow, some apps do not understand the permissions (Best Buy app is like this) and it can't locate you properly. The only fix for those is to have the developer update the app for Marshmallow.

Comment: @acejavelin isn't that supposed to be an answer, despite of being short? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just click Back (the sideways triangle at the bottom), it should take you back to your app and just work. Note that if you are on Marshmallow, some apps do not understand the permissions (Best Buy app is like this) and it can't locate you properly. The only fix for those is to have the developer update the app for Marshmallow.